# Conversion from Shapefile to TopoJSON format results in incorrect map when rendered using d3js

Tags: geojson, canada, d3, topojson

I am trying to build a map of Canada showing FSA boundaries using d3js. I got shape data from Statistics Canada [http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/bound-limit-2011-eng.cfm].

To convert the SHP file to topojson, I am following the process from Mike Bostock's Tutorial 'Lets Build a Map' [http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/].

First convert the map to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr, then using topojson in Node.js, convert the GeoJSON file to a TopoJSON file.

I am executing the commands:

```
> ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -s_srs EPSG:21781 -t_srs EPSG:4326 output.geojson input.shp
```

Followed by the command:

```
 > topojson --id-property CFSAUID -p name=PRNAME -p name -o output.topojson output.geojson
```

The resulting map that is generated renders some provinces properly, however, the following provinces show up as jumbled lines.

- Ontario
- Newfoundland
- Quebec
- Manitoba
- Saskatchewan
- Alberta
- British Columbia

Here is a basic version of my d3 call.

```
var g = svg.append("g").attr("id", "fsa");
d3.json("can/output.json", function (error, json) {
    var counter = 0;
    var subunits = topojson.object(json, data);
    g.selectAll("path")
    .data(subunits.output)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)        
});
```

Comment: If -s_crs means source crs, I think the 21781 code is wrong. That's a projected crs for Switzerland. The census data I downloaded has a prj file that lists NAD 1983, EPSG:4269, a geographic CRS.

Comment: As @mbostock says in his answer, the problem is with the projection. By specifying the mercator projection canada renders properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [default projection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#wiki-projection) in D3 is the U.S.-centric [d3.geo.albersUsa](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-albersUsa) projection. This is a composite projection design to display the 48 contiguous United States, Hawaii, Alaska and Puerto Rico. If you want to make a map of Canada, you’ll have to specify the appropriate projection rather than relying on the default.

Comment: Thanks so much, it seems to be working now. Apologies for the duplicate post. I did not know it is against the rules, now I do. :)